# Persistently hide cursor [evil-mode problem]

Tags: buffers, visibility

If I hide the cursor in a buffer with

```
(setq cursor-type nil)
```

it will reappear if I move it around.

Is there a way for hiding the cursor all the time (only for one specific buffer)?

Comment: My bet is on Evil being the culprit.  Here's [a bug report](https://bitbucket.org/lyro/evil/issues/592/evil-makes-hidden-cursor-reappear-on) I've handed in.

Comment: @wasamasa Thanks, yes you are right I'm using Evil and it works if I disable it. The function suggested by lawlist is a good alternative and seems to work around this problem.

Comment: bug report in the new(est) evil bug tracker: https://github.com/emacs-evil/evil/issues/592

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I am aware, moving the cursor around should *not* magically make the cursor reappear.  Try out a default **Emacs -Q** and see if the behavior is present or not.  Setting the variable `cursor-type` to `nil` in a particular buffer should achieve the visual effect desired.

---

*See Also*:  The popular built-in `blink-cursor-mode` uses `internal-show-cursor` to hide the cursor in a specific window rather than a buffer:

`internal-show-cursor` is a built-in function in `C source code'.

```
(internal-show-cursor WINDOW SHOW)

Set the cursor-visibility flag of WINDOW to SHOW.
WINDOW nil means use the selected window.  SHOW non-nil means
show a cursor in WINDOW in the next redisplay.  SHOW nil means
don’t show a cursor.
```

Comment: As wasmasa assumed in his comment it is a problem with evil-mode. But internal-show-cursor works for me, thanks!